# Isolation Forest height limit absent in SkLearn implementation

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees, outlier

In the [original publication](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/tkdd11.pdf) of the Isolation Forest algorithm, the authors mention a height limit parameter to control the granularity of the algorithm. I did not find that explicit parameter on the Sklearn implementation of the algorithm, and I was wondering whether it is possible to control granularity in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like there is no `hlim` parameter incorporated into `sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest`. [Calculation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py#L281) of anomaly score is just based on the depth each point settles to and by the average path length. The only way to tune in a bit is by using contamination which calculates the [threshold](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py#L203) needed to set for anomaly score.

To achieve the granularity that was given in the original paper using `hlim=6` to detect a cluster of small points, using a lot of estimators may solve the problem (still depends heavily on how you sample data from smaller cluster into a lot of estimators). But if that small cluster of data is very less in number, I don't think this idea works and there is nothing much we can do from the current implementation in [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mario I guess you deleted the question.

Comment: Hi, I had to leave the post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514143/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest).

Answer (score 1):

In "Isolation Forest" paper, it is said:

[image]

I think that is why you don't find it in the scikit-learn.